# Laravel. Form validation errors disappearing if there are too many of them

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I have come across some very weird behaviour in Laravel. In my Request I have some validation rules like this:

```
'field_1' => 'required',
'field_2' => 'required'
```

If I submit this form without those fields, I see errors. However, If I have more than 8 failing validation rules or so, then I dont see any errors at all! `$errors` variable in View suddenly is empty. The request still fails and dont execute Controller code, but it returns back without any errors at all..

```
'field_1' => 'required',
'field_2' => 'required',
'field_3' => 'required',
'field_4' => 'required',
'field_5' => 'required',
'field_6' => 'required',
'field_7' => 'required',
'field_8' => 'required',
// No errors displayed in View, but Request returns me back, like if it has failed
```

Looks like it has something to do with response's length. If error messages get longer than something (not sure what exactly) then they dont appear in `$errors` variable in View.

This is very strange. How do I solve this? I need A LOT of error messages..

In my view:

```
@if ($errors->has())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @foreach (array_unique( $errors->all() ) as $error)
            {{ $error }}<br>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif

@if(Session::has('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ Session::get('error') }}
    </div>
@endif

@if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ Session::get('success') }}
    </div>
@endif

@include('flash::message')
```

Comment: Can you post your error passing to the view code? I think it might give some clues

Comment: @insanebits updated. Nothing really interesting there, however.

Comment: Did you found out what was the causing this behaviour? Suddenly I'm having exactly same thing, yet I can't see what affects to it, other than the amount of validated/failing fields.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is bit late to answer but I was facing same issue. I just checked my `session.php` in `config` and found that my driver was set to `cookie`. I just changed it to `file` and everything seemed to work. I hope this might help you or anyone struggling with this error.

Comment: Hello , may i know why this was down vote so that it will help improve my answering method in future.

Comment: This fixed my issue as well. It seems the `cookie` session is limited to a fixed amount of messages and the `file` session is not.

Comment: Still true for Laravel 8! You saved me a wild ride into the validation process, friend.